# get screenwidth on page visit with vbscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, vbscript, asp-classic

Having some issues here.
My goal is when you visit a page, javascript gets the browser width and sets it as a cookie. A few more lines down the page, vbscript picks up the cookie, reads the value and determines whether to display content or not. This is what I have so far:

```
<script> 
var width = $(window).width();
document.cookie = 'ScreenWidth=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;';
document.cookie = 'ScreenWidth='+width; 
</script>
<%
    Dim ScreenWidth
    Dim minWidth
    minWidth = 768
    ScreenWidth=request.Cookies("ScreenWidth")
    'response.Write("screen width: "&ScreenWidth)
    If ScreenWidth > minWidth Then
       'display code
    End If
%>
```

When you first load the page, nothing happens. If you go to the page and refresh it, then it starts working. While it does work, it's not very good usability. Is there something I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the cookie is created after the VBScript is executed, so the VBScript doesn't see the cookie until the next load.

I would consider making the changes on the page using ajax so it renders as it should on first load.

You can view [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for details on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The ASP code (the part between `<% %>`) is executed on the server side (i.e. *before* the page is delivered to the client), whereas the JavaScript code is executed on the client side (i.e. *after* the page is delivered to the client). Effectively you're trying to read the cookie before it's actually created. You need to make your display code client-side code (preferably JavaScript).